# PostGis -> ST_Contains: how to check in which BBox of a table is the current BBox

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a table `graphs` with a column `bbox`.

This column contains geometry and I save all kinds of bboxes there

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('graphs', 'bbox', 4326, 'POLYGON', 2 );
```

How could I check in which **Bbox** from `column bbox` lays the current `bbox`?

As I understand I have to do it with `ST_Contains` but I need a little help regarding the syntax.

I tried this kind of approach:

```
SELECT bbox,BBOX_Diagonale,file FROM graphs WHERE ST_CONTAINS(bbox,ST_MakeEnvelope( 11.58624574 , 47.71313579 , 12.21446607 , 48.13538804 , 4326)) order by BBOX_Diagonale ASC LIMIT 1;
```

And my table has these values:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------
left_xmin   | 11.66952931
bottom_ymin | 47.79336862
right_xmax  | 12.18612053
top_ymax    | 48.14030283
filename    | my_sfn_cache1619119545.38177
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----------------------------
left_xmin   | 11.58624574
bottom_ymin | 47.71313579
right_xmax  | 12.21446607
top_ymax    | 48.13538804
filename    | my_sfn_cache1619119600.90796
```

So this query should provide me at least one entry fromm the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a small mistake where I write to db. Basically number mixup. Anyway if someone want to know how to find bbox that is inside other one in db this is how you do it.

Comment: Well there is basically not much to add. If you have a table with geo column (in this case it is called bbox) you can use the select command i posted just with different values which describe a bbox and you will get a matching bbox from the database where the the box from your select command fits in.

Comment: Oh sorry :) it is jst a pointer to the post... ill remove it.